# How can I dynamically initialize items from the class constructor?

Tags: c#, class, types, constructor

In my class constructor I am initializing many List[DropDownItem] lists ..... I don't want to have to list all of them in the constructor anymore, I want them to be initialized auto-magically.

I have the following, which can identify the type I need to target, but I can't get it across the goal line yet. Can't figure out how to do the "obj = new List(); part.

```
private void initializeDropdownItemLists(Type T)
{
    var props = typeof(UserEditModel).GetProperties();

    foreach (var p in props)
    {
        var type = p.PropertyType;
        if (type.IsGenericType && type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(List<>))
        {
            var itemType = type.GetGenericArguments()[0];

            if (itemType == typeof(DropdownItem))
            {
                p.SetValue(T, new List<DropdownItem>());
            }
        }

    }
}


public class UserEditModel
{
    public UserEditModel()
    {
        selectedUser = new UserBusinessModel();
        currentUser = new UserBusinessModel();

        //  I want to replace this
        ddl1 = new List<DropdownItem>();
        ddl2 = new List<DropdownItem>();
        ddl3 = new List<DropdownItem>();
        ddl4 = new List<DropdownItem>();
        ddl5 = new List<DropdownItem>();
        ddl6 = new List<DropdownItem>();
        ddl7 = new List<DropdownItem>();
        ddl8 = new List<DropdownItem>();
        ddl9 = new List<DropdownItem>();
        ddl10 = new List<DropdownItem>();

        //  with this
        this.initializeDropdownItemLists();

        //  or better yet this, ..... pass the class type so then any similar class can use it
        someHelper.initializeDropdownItemLists(typeof(UserEditModel));
    }

    public UserBusinessModel currentUser { get; set; }
    public UserBusinessModel selectedUser { get; set; }

    //  other properties omitted for brevity ...
}
```

Comment: I can't see the `obj = new List()` part which you mention...

Comment: You'll need to pass the method a `UserEditModel`, or write `var userEditModel = new UserEditModel()` at the start of the method. Then, you'd write: `p.SetValue(userEditModel, new List<DropdownItem>());`

Comment: I made some changes based off your comment and i get error: Object does not match target type. I must be doing something wrong. This is a bit out of my depth.

Comment: Why not just give the backing fields an initializer, why use reflection code that you will have to carefully read later to see what it does?

Comment: Lasse, I don't follow what you mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following code:

```
p.SetValue(someUserEditModelObject, new List<DropdownItem>());
```

where someUserEditModelObject is object passed to initializeDropdownItemLists method.

EDIT:
Code for generic helper:

```
    public class Helper
    {
        public void InitializeDropdownItemLists<T>(T model)
        {
            var props = typeof (T).GetProperties();

            foreach (var p in props)
            {
                var type = p.PropertyType;
                if (type.IsGenericType && type.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof (List<>))
                {
                    var itemType = type.GetGenericArguments()[0];

                    if (itemType == typeof (DropdownItem))
                    {
                        p.SetValue(model, new List<DropdownItem>());
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: you shouldn't pass to initialize method typeof(UserEditModel) pass "this": `someHelper.initializeDropdownItemLists(this);` and change private void initializeDropdownItemLists(Type T) to `private void initializeDropdownItemLists(UserEditModel T)`

Comment: another case is to make it generic, then you must declare method as following: `private void initializeDropdownItemLists<T>(T model)` and change p.SetValue(T, new List<DropdownItem>()); to `p.SetValue(model, new List<DropdownItem>());`